# MAMP Pro 2.0.3 doesn't work in OS X Lion

Tags: apache-http-server, osx-lion, mamp

When I start MAMP Pro 2.0.3 on Mac OS X Lion I get the following error:

> Apache wasn't able to start. Please check log for more information.

When I look at the Console it says:

> kernel: nstat_lookup_entry failed: 2

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: From what I find online, that kernel error is quite common. Disable mamp and restart and make sure the errors are actually related.

Comment: I called Apple phone support and this is apparently an issue with my installation of Lion Server. Thanks for your help, I am going to have to restore my computer to before installing server, as I did not configure it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a thread on this: [nstat_lookup_entry failed:2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3200365?start=15&tstart=0) ..

Comment: Where is the solution in that thread?